# Excel shared spreadsheet, iPhone changes appearance of CHAR function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, iphone

I have an Excel 2016 spreadsheet which I want to be able to edit on my iPhone as well as my laptop. I've set up certain cells to display a tick/cross if a certain thing is done or not using the CHAR function.

The problem arises when I edit the spreadsheet on my iPhone: the characters change. CHAR(252) ([Tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLRyL.png)) becomes CHAR(184) ([2-o'clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwr3C.png)), and CHAR(251) ([Cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnN03.png)) becomes CHAR(218) ([Downward arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrbpL.png)). But here's the interesting part: the actual cell contents (CHAR(252)) don't change. It's the appearance of the cells. They appear to change from one character to another.

When I re-open the spreadsheet on my laptop, the characters are displayed incorrectly still. The only fix I have is to do a fill on all the incorrect cells, and then hit CTRL+Z. That fixes the issue, but it's a rubbish workaround.

Has anyone else ever come across such a bizarre issue before?? 
And is there a fix? Using the CHAR function is the only way I can display a tick or cross, so I don't particularly want to forego that functionality.

I'm open to suggestions and thoughts.

N.B. I'm using the Wingdings font as that's the only one that has a tick and cross symbol.

Comment: It could well be a difference in the font between your mobile and desktop. You might be able to embed the font in the excel file in the Excel options.

Comment: I've checked, you can't embed fonts into Excel. Only into Word/Powerpoint. There is a workaround: you can embed the whole workbook in a word document. But I haven't experimented with that. I don't know if I'd be able to edit the cells, on desktop or iPhone. Or if it would open at all on the iPhone. Think I'm SOL on this one, thanks for the comment though